# NetSuite: TypeError: log.debug is not a function in Client Script (SuiteScript 2.0)

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript2.0

I’m using N/Log module in Client Scripts in my bundle. 
But got an error "TypeError: log.debug is not a function" in one of NetSuite Account that uses my bundle.

when I try to load N/Log module using the browser console N / log module is injected as a Suitelet 1.0 function instead of the Suitelet 2.0 Module.

My questions are:

- Is it possible to explicitly inject or redefine N/Log Suitelet 2.0 Module in Client Script?
- What can affect the injection of modules? (other scripts or NS configuration)

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.0
 *@NScriptType ClientScript
 *@NModuleScope Public
 */

define(
[
  'N/record',
  'N/search',
  'N/currentRecord',
  'N/url',
  'N/https',
  'N/runtime',
  'N/ui/dialog',
  'N/log',
  'N/error',

],
function(
  record,
  search,
  currentRecord,
  url,
  https,
  runtime,
  dialog,
  log,
  error,

) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

The means one of the declarations before log  is not a true module

Answer (score -1):

You may use: `log('type', 'title', 'details')`

Example:

```
log('debug', 'Test', x);
```